# Search field ignored after returning from question

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Search for a keyword using the search EditText.
2. Click any question from the search result.  This will open the question.
3. Press the back button to go back to the previous screen.
4. Use the pull to refresh feature: this loads questions without taking the search terms into consideration. Though the terms are still present in the EditText.

Special case:

When the search yields results that do not fill the ListView, upon going back (step 3) a ProgressBar will be shown below the results indicating new content is loading. Yet nothing really is.

Example: search for *android-app search cleared*.  You should get 2 results.

Comment: don't know why this was downvoted... +1 to offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report! Fixed in version 0.1.72 coming out later tonight UTC.